# set a subdomain with redirect to the index page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have the domain abdefg.it.

I have set the subdomain sub.abcdefg.it pointing in the directory that contain:

```
index.php
folderA
.htaccess
```

The problem is that if I type the url `sub.abcdefg.it` an error appear, but if I type `sub.abcdefg.it/index.php` all goes well.

That is what is contained in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.abcdefg\.it$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sub\.abcdefg\.it$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.abcdefg\.it\/sub\/index\.php" [R=301,L]
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?sub\.abcdefg\.it$
RewriteRule .* http://www.abcdefg.it/sub/index.php [R=301,L]
```

Now, you just redirect HTTP_HOST.

Before all work well, use [R=302,L] for tests, without cache.